Playwright test fails via github actions but passes locally within docker image (Nektos Act)
What is being tested:
Web application: https://projects-app-front-end.onrender.com/learning.
Test failure details:
My playwright e2e test suite passes locally, but consistently fails at the same place during a github action workflow.  The action unfortunately doesn't save the test report contrary to the workflow definition so I can't debug what is happening at the specific point of failure.
Workflow .yml
name: Playwright Tests

on:
  push:
    branches: [main, master]
  pull_request:
    branches: [main, master]

  env:
    BASE_API_URL: ${{ vars.BASE_API_URL }}
    BASE_FRONTEND_URL: ${{ vars.BASE_FRONTEND_URL }}
    PW: ${{ vars.PW }}

defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: ./Projects_EndToEndTests

permissions:
  pull-requests: write

jobs:
  workflow-telemetry-action:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Collect Workflow Telemetry
        uses: catchpoint/workflow-telemetry-action@v2
  test:
    timeout-minutes: 60
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: lts/*
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci
      - name: Install Playwright Browsers
        run: npx playwright install chromium --with-deps
      - name: Run Playwright tests
        run: npx playwright test --project=e2e-test
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        if: ${{ !cancelled() }}
        with:
          name: playwright-report
          path: playwright-report/
          retention-days: 30

Playwright.config.
import { defineConfig, devices } from "@playwright/test";

/**
 * Read environment variables from file.
 * https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv
 */
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import path from "path";
dotenv.config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, ".env") });

export const STORAGE_STATE = path.join(__dirname, "playwright/.auth/user.json");

/**
 * See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-configuration.
 */
export default defineConfig({
  // timeout: 100000,
  testDir: "./tests",
  /* Run tests in files in parallel */
  fullyParallel: true,
  /* Fail the build on CI if you accidentally left test.only in the source code. */
  forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
  /* Retry on CI only */
  // retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,
  retries: 0,
  /* Opt out of parallel tests on CI. */
  workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,
  /* Reporter to use. See https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters */
  reporter: "html",
  /* Shared settings for all the projects below. See https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testoptions. */
  use: {
    /* Base URL to use in actions like `await page.goto('/')`. */
    // baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000',

    /* Collect trace when retrying the failed test. See https://playwright.dev/docs/trace-viewer */
    // trace: "on-first-retry",
    trace: "retain-on-failure",
  },

  /* Configure projects for major browsers */
  projects: [
    {
      name: "setup",
      testMatch: "**/*setup.ts",
    },
    {
      name: "e2e-test",
      testMatch: "**/*projects-e2e.spec.ts",
      dependencies: ["setup"],
      use: {
        storageState: STORAGE_STATE,
      },
    },
    {
      name: "chromium",
      use: { ...devices["Desktop Chrome"] },
    },

The test suite begins with a setup step that initialises the database with x3 MS Projects on which the tests rely.  The files (.xml) are uploaded via a web form, each file is <500kb.  Two project files are uploaded successfully but the third fails to upload, even with an extended timeout allowance.  The test finally fails due to the lack of file upload and that it isn't visible in the UI (so a playwright assertion isn't met). There is nothing unusual about the third file that during upload appears to cause the workflow to hang.
File upload time is approximately 20-30s (when it works)
I have two questions:

Why do I not get a test report for me to view and help with debug? :
"Run actions/upload-artifact@v4
Warning: No files were found with the provided path: playwright-report/. No artifacts will be uploaded."
Why does the test consistently pass locally, run directly in the playwright folder or with a nektos act docker instance? But fail within a Github action workflow?

I have deployed a recent locally run Playwright test report for reference here: https://jdineley.github.io/Projects_app/
(Using GH actions the test fails at login & MS Project upload)
